# Factory Service is always undefined

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I've spent a few hours trying to debug this with no real breakthroughs. My console.logs correctly output the load order.
- app
- factory
- controller
I'm annotating my dependencies (even though I'm not minifying at the moment).

*Is there anything obviously wrong here that I am missing?*

**error**
[image]

**app**

```
(function () {
'use strict';
console.log("running app");
var app = angular.module('InventoryProductApp', []).config(function ($logProvider) {
    $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
});
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    var app = document.getElementById('InventoryProductApp');
    angular.bootstrap(angular.element(app), ['InventoryProductApp']);
});
})();
```

**controller**

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('InventoryProductApp').controller("LocationsController", ['$scope', '$log', 'LocationsFactory'
, function ($scope, $http, $log, LocationsFactory) {
    console.log("running controller");
    $scope.locations = null;
    $scope.loading = false;

    //private methods -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    var fetchLocationData = function (inventoryId) {
        $scope.loading = true;
        console.log(LocationsFactory);
        var promise = LocationsFactory.getLocationData(inventoryId);

        promise.then(function (data) {
            $scope.loading = false;

            if (data.success) {
                $scope.locations = data.locations;
            }
            else
            {
                $log.error('There was an error getting location data');
            }

        }, function (data) {
            $scope.loading = false;
            $log.error('There was an error getting location data');
        });
    }

    //end private methods ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    //public methods --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    var init = function (inventoryId) {
        console.log('inventoryId', inventoryId);
        fetchLocationData(inventoryId);
    }
    //end public methods ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    init(inventoryId); // inventoryId is found in the partialView _inventoryLocationDistribution
}]);
})();
```

**factory**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('InventoryProductApp').factory('LocationsFactory', ['$http', '$q', '$log', function ($http, $q, $log) {
    console.log("running factory");
    return {
        getLocationData: function (inventoryId) {
            var def = $q.defer();

            $http.get('/butthead', {
                params: {
                    inventoryId: inventoryId
                }
            }).then(function (response) {
                def.resolve({
                    success: true,
                    locations: data.locations
                });
            }, function (response) {
                $log.error('failed to fetch data', response);
                def.resolve({
                    success: false,
                    redirect: response.redirect
                });
            });

            return def.promise;
        }
    }
}]);
})();
```

**script load order**

```
<script src="~/theme/modern/assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/App/Inventory/Product/ProductApp.js"></script>
<script src="~/App/Inventory/Product/LocationsFactory.js"></script>
<script src="~/App/Inventory/Product/LocationsController.js"></script>
```

Comment: Post your error as text, not as an image.

Comment: Use ng-annotate, and be done with this ugly, verbose, error-prone array notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller:

```
angular.module('InventoryProductApp').controller("LocationsController",    
    ['$scope', '$log', 'LocationsFactory', function ($scope, $http, $log, LocationsFactory) {
```

You're missing `'$http'` in your dependency injections, which means the `LocationsFactory` argument isn't filled at all.